# Количество рабочих дней между двумя датами

Tags: python, datetime

У меня есть код:

```
start_day: datetime.datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(
  "06.10.2023 16:10", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"
)
current_day: datetime.datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(
  "09.10.2023 16:10", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"
)
days_without_defects: datetime.timedelta = current_day - start_day
```

Он выведет мне

```
3 days, 0:00:00
```

Хотя мы расчитывали разницу между пятницой и понедельником.
Я понимаю что можно прибегнуть к библиотеке numpy, а конкретно к методу **np.busday_count** но он не учитывает часы. Как мне решить данную проблему не используя никаких данных json касаемо праздничных дней и тд?

Comment: Что такое "рабочий день", промежуток времени (сколько секунд, минут..), время когда солнце высоко ( какое конкретно) или что-то иное?

Comment: @Oopss имеется ввиду пн-пт

Comment: а что должно получиться для приведенных данных?

Comment: @Эникейщик так как первый флажок установлен на 6ое число 16:10, а второй на 9ое 16:10, то прошло (не учитывая выходные) 24 часа, т.е 1 день

Comment: `rrule` из `python-dateutil` посмотрите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Считаю вашу концепцию подсчета рабочих дней не правильной, но задача интересная, предлагаю не оптимальное решение, проверять каждое приращение времени является ли этот момент субботой или воскресеньем, можно использовать приращение равное секунде, минуте или любому промежутку времени. Естественно государственные праздники какой-либо страны не могут быть учтены.

```
import datetime


def r_weekday(t_start, t_finish):
    if isinstance(t_start, datetime.datetime) and isinstance(t_finish, datetime.datetime):
        dt = t_finish - t_start           # общее время от начала до конца
        pp = datetime.timedelta(seconds=0)# Начальное значение приращения
        total_time = 0
        while pp < dt:                    # Пока сумма приращений меньше общего времени
            wd = (t_start + pp).weekday() # День недели в момент времени
            if wd <= 4:
                total_time += 1
            pp += datetime.timedelta(seconds=1) # Приращение в одну секунду
        return total_time
    else:
        return -1

def seconds_to_dhms(seconds): # перевод секунд в день час мин сек
    days = seconds // (3600 * 24)
    hours = (seconds // 3600) % 24
    minutes = (seconds // 60) % 60
    seconds = seconds % 60
    return days, hours, minutes, seconds

start_day: datetime.datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(
    "06.10.2023 16:10", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"
)


current_day: datetime.datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(
  "09.10.2023 16:10", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"
)
print(seconds_to_dhms(r_weekday(start_day, current_day)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы получил бы временной ряд в pandas и после выборки нужных данных посчитал бы сумму. Будем считать, что рабочий день все-таки начинается и заканчивается не в полночь. В коде ниже рабочий день обозначен с 9 утра до 18 вечера, current_day я сделал "09.10.2023 16:20", чтобы добавить минуты:

```
import pandas as pd

bdays = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.date_range(
    start_day, current_day,
    freq=pd.offsets.BusinessHour(start="09:00", end="18:00"))).reset_index()
bdays["duration"] = bdays["index"].diff()
res = bdays.loc[bdays["duration"]==pd.Timedelta("1H"), "duration"].sum() +\
                pd.to_datetime(current_day) - bdays["index"].iloc[-1]
print(res)
```

> 0 days 08:10:00